# How to change the page layout back and forth?

Tags: page-breaking, margins, geometry

I'm trying to do some absolute placement on a page but because I use `pdflscape`, I can't use the `textpos` package for this. I tried around a bit with moving with `\hspace*` and `\vspace*` but this is very tedious and produces overfull boxes galore. So I tried to change the page layout for just one page which basically works but the *next* page is broken in ways I cannot comprehend.

Here is what I did; I store the old dimensions, set everything to zero or whatever (pdf)LaTeX needs to make it zero and then restore the old dimensions from the saved values:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newlength{\oldtextheight}
\newlength{\oldtextwidth}
\newlength{\oldevensidemargin}
\newlength{\oldoddsidemargin}
\newlength{\oldcolumnsep}
\newlength{\oldtopmargin}
\newlength{\oldheadheight}
\newlength{\oldheadsep}
\newlength{\oldfootskip}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[5]

\newpage%
% save old page dimensions
\setlength{\oldtextheight}{\textheight}%
\setlength{\oldtextwidth}{\textwidth}%
\setlength{\oldevensidemargin}{\evensidemargin}%
\setlength{\oldoddsidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}%
\setlength{\oldcolumnsep}{\columnsep}%
\setlength{\oldtopmargin}{\topmargin}%
\setlength{\oldheadheight}{\headheight}%
\setlength{\oldheadsep}{\headsep}%
\setlength{\oldfootskip}{\footskip}%
% set all margins to 0
\setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight}%
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}%
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-1in}%
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-1in}%
\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1in}%
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}%
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\footskip}{0pt}%
% do absolute placement stuff where textpos doesn't work:
\noindent\rule{5mm}{5mm}\newpage% the necessity for this \newpage is also strange
% reset page dimensions
\setlength{\textheight}{\oldtextheight}%
\setlength{\textwidth}{\oldtextwidth}%
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oldevensidemargin}%
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{\oldoddsidemargin}%
\setlength{\columnsep}{\oldcolumnsep}%
\setlength{\topmargin}{\oldtopmargin}%
\setlength{\headheight}{\oldheadheight}%
\setlength{\headsep}{\oldheadsep}%
\setlength{\footskip}{\oldfootskip}%
%\newpage % this wouldn't help a bit

\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

While the margins seem more or less intact, the type area is larger than the actual page. As I reset `\textheight` along with everything else, this makes no sense to me. The following image shows page 3 from the above example (click to enlarge):

[image]

One page later, everything is back to normal. Any help on what is happening and how I can make a clean reset would be much appreciated.

Maybe I should add that I've read that newer versions of the `geometry` package have `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` commands that appear to do just what I'm trying to do manually but the TeXLive distribution on my current Beta Ubuntu (Precise) isn't new enough and I'd rather not mess with my package manager (it always pays me back one day) or my TeX trees in general (it's dark art and never works like it should).

I did try the `gmeometric` package (`\geometry{textheight=\paperheight,textwidth=\paperwidth}` and `\geometry{textheight=\oldtextheight,textwidth=\oldtextwidth}`) but to no avail.

Comment: Why don't you install TeX LIve 2011?

Comment: the `geometry` package is definitely a good way to go here. are you using the `texlive` from the repositories? if so, you'll want to get rid of it in favour of texlive 2011 from the tug website

Comment: I'd rather not mess with my package manager and I don't want to install a complete (or partial for that matter) second TeX tree. If there's a well-maintained PPA that would be an option.

Comment: After breaking my rules and messing with my package management by manually installing TeXLive and following a howto that pretended I could make it all right and explain what I did to the package manager, I got punished and spend a lot of time yesterday to get everything back to where I started. I then found this PPA https://launchpad.net/~texlive-backports/+archive/ppa which does a better but not perfect job of integrating with an existing Ubuntu 12.04. The good news is that the new `geometry` works as expected. I didn't find out what magic geometry does and I'd still be thankful for answers.

Comment: @Christian We don't use [tag:layout] or similar tags; for details see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1300/the-layout-tag-is-redundant.

Comment: @lockstep Sorry, I wasn't aware of this policy. I wanted to use {type-area} at first but there's already the {typearea} tag but it's about the package of that name, not about the macrotypographic concept of print space.

Comment: @Christian Indeed, the [tag:margins] tag is quite appropriate here.

Comment: @lockstep Agreed, given the the description of {margins} this seems to be perfect. Thanks for correcting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can afford to make your code depend on a version of `geometry` that is not yet included in Debian, Ubuntu nor in Fedora, you can use the following code to replace the one in the question. It is much shorter to be sure.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{geometry}[2010/09/12]
\begin{document}

\blindtext[5]

\newgeometry{textheight=\paperheight,textwidth=\paperwidth}
% do absolute placement stuff where textpos doesn't work:
\noindent\rule{5mm}{5mm}
\restoregeometry

\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

I couldn't make out which trick `geometry` uses though. The last thing `\restoregeometry` does is to invoke `\Gm@changelayout` which just sets some lengths, some standard, some internal to `geometry`. Not even so much as a `\clearpage`.

So an answer that actually explains why the code in the question behaves so strangely would still be much appreciated and accepted as correct answer.

Comment: Actually, the *first* token executed by `\restoregeometry` is `\clearpage`. To see this, issue `\show\restoregeometry` and inspect your `.log`. Similarly, the *first* token executed by `\newgeometry` is also `\clearpage`. So, the behaviour of both macros is expected.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. I also do a `\clearpage` before setting the layout lengths. Well, actually a `\newpage` in the code above but I originally did a `\clearpage` because I needed it anyway and it showed the same broken behaviour. I just thought for the sake of a minimal example `\newpage` would do.

Comment: Your MWE does not include a `\newpage` nor a `\clearpage`, so I don't know what you're commenting on.

Comment: Maybe it's a bit hidden but: `\noindent\rule{5mm}{5mm}\newpage`

Comment: BTW, if I comment out that `\newpage`, the length changes _before_ that don't get applied. That's what the source code comment aimed at. Adding another `\newpage` after the resetting of the lengths doesn't change the broken next page a bit. I truly don't understand when the \newpage would have to go before the layout changes, when afterwards and in which cases the layout just doesn't care. Let me also again highlight the point that most lengths do take effect, just not the `\textheight` from the sight of it. `layouts` lied to my face by showing _all_ lengths as normal.